# Performance issue with set of images on map

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

Need to add about 400 images(markers) to map. Images are drawables, not bitmap pictures. Is it correct way to do it?

```
GeoJsonSource source;
mapboxMap.addSource(source);

for(Item item : items){

        Bitmap bitmap;
        SymbolLayer markerLayer = new SymbolLayer("layerA", sourceId);

        markerLayer.withProperties(PropertyFactory.iconImage(imageId));
        markerLayer.setFilter(
                all(
                        eq("id", item.getId()),
                        eq("coordinates", item.getLatLng())
                )
        );

        mapboxMap.addLayer(markerLayer, layerId);
        mapboxMap.addImage(imageId, bitmap);

}
```

With this method map becomes unresponsive and fps drops significantly. Probably this is just limitation of the map engine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a array of that drawable images, Store all images in that .

like

```
int[] images = new int[] {};//store all images {in here}
```

Then use map icons by by their positions.. Or create a for loop

like

```
for (int i = 0;i<images.lenght;i++){
//apply your code here and set the images
mapboxMap.addImage(imageId, bitmap.get[i]);
}
```

May be It will help You..